# 2fa not working in twitter oauth

Tags: oauth, electron, twitter-oauth

I’m writing an Electron app that requires access to a user's Twitter account. OAuth without 2FA works fine.

But whenever I try to authenticate with an account that has 2FA turned on, the Twitter login page doesn’t redirect me to the code input page. I know Twitter has validated my password, because I immediately get an SMS with the code, but there’s nowhere for me to put it!

I tried app passwords to avoid turning off 2FA but they didn’t work.

Authentication with that account only worked after turning off 2FA altogether. But that’s not something I can tell my users to do.

Has anyone else experienced this?

I tried disabling all my Chrome extensions, and also ran this project on a totally new machine in case my Chrome installation was messed up. No dice. (Not sure if there's any connection between my machine's Chrome installation and Electron, but thought it was worth a try).

FWIW, here's what the console is showing (but note that these errors show before any attempt to log in):

[image]

Comment: what are you setting as your `oauth_callback`

Comment: it's set to `http://127.0.0.1` in the twitter settings. i've tried setting it to `http://127.0.0.1/` and `null` on my side in the request...but got the same result. not sure what else to try since it's a local application.

Comment: hey, thanks for the pointer! looks like you implemented pin-based auth. i was working toward implementing that in my app by looking at your example when the maintainer of `electron-oauth-twitter` pushed an update that accommodates 2fa! https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-oauth-twitter